# Add sanitizers only to debug build in CMake

Tags: cmake

I am trying to add sanitizers to debug build only in CMake. As I understand:

1. normally you add sanitizers like this:

   ```
   set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -fsanitize=address,undefined")
   ```
2. for compatibility with Visual Studio (and other multi-configuration generators), I need to use a generator expression

   ```
   $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=address,undefined>
   ```

   instead of e.g. `if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")`.

So how do I combine them? I tried

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} $<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=address,undefined>")
```

and

```
set(SANITIZE_FLAGS "$<$<CONFIG:Debug>:-fsanitize=address,undefined>")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${SANITIZE_FLAGS}")
```

Both lead to errors looking like

```
no such file or directory: '../../../src/ffn.cc../../../src/ffn.ccCONFIG:Debug'
```

Comment: For add flags only for `Debug` configuration just append them into `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` variable. This works for multi-configuration generators too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks! Can you make this an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way for set **compiler flags** only for **specific configuration** (build type) is appending these flags to corresponded [CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_FLAGS_CONFIG.html) variable:

```
# Add sanitizer flags for C++ compiler for "Debug" configuration
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG} -fsanitize=address,undefined")
```

This way works perfectly in case of multi-configuration generators like Visual Studio.

---

Setting `CMAKE_<LANG>_FLAGS_<CONFIG>` variable works even for **custom** build types. Here `<CONFIG>` is *upper-case* variant of a build type.